# Can I add a socket to my boiler power circuit?

Tags: bedroom, socket

I would like to add a socket for my daughter to charge her phone and tablet by her bed. her bed is against the cupboard which houses the boiler, inside the cupboard is a socket which the boiler is plugged into. Its not on the ring main its a dedicated cable straight from the consumer unit on its own trip, its a gas combi boiler.
Can i use this socket to get the power from to put a socket by her bed.
Im based in the uk

Comment: Not a good idea to add anything to the boiler power circuit.

Comment: Sounds like it'll be in parallel. Be better that way.

Comment: I am not sure with your electrical code regulations but on this side of the pond the heating / furnace circuit is supposed to be dedicated to heating equipment only. It would be a violation to add another non heating use to the circuit. Where in the world are you located?

Comment: I tried to clean up the question, grammar, formatting to make this a little more clear. Please review to ensure that I've not modified the intent of your question, since it was unclear to start with.

Comment: If it is a gas boiler it's OK.

Comment: Im i  the uk, would like to add a double socket but dont want to lift carpet and all to tap into the ring main. But wanted to see if i could tap into this outlet and run another one from it

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question is very confusing. If there is a wall receptacle near where she wants to charge her stuff, just buy an adapter that plugs into a wall socket. If the socket is too far away for her charge cords, go to a store and buy a longer charge cord. I have charge cords 10 feet long just for that purpose. If this does not solve your problem try to give a better explanation of what you want to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the US this would be a code violation.

Comment: Agree 100% - using a longer USB cable to reach an existing socket (or, perhaps an extension cord) is a _far_ better option than tapping into the wiring going to the boiler.

Comment: a mains extension cord would charge the phone faster than a 10' usb cable.

Comment: @dandavis how so? Wouldn't you need to plug an adapter in either way? Once you're at the adapter, charging speed depends on how much power the adapter provides and what (if any) quick charging technology it supports vs what the device supports. I use a 10' USB cable from my wall-wort to my phone and my phone reports "Turbo charging connected", gets nice and toasty warm, and charges quite quickly...

Comment: @FreeMan: there's a huge range of quality in such cables. given that, shorter is better. If you're using PD@18v it doesn't matter as much as plain old 5v, but either way, it's better to put the unavoidable ohms against 110/220v than 5/12/18v.

Comment: Fair enough, @dandavis (_as we wander way off topic_) if the device recognizes a "quick charge" (of whatever brand/labeling) on a 10' USB cable, it'll still do a quick charge, no matter the quality of cable, will it not? That will provide a charge just as quickly as an extension cord & shorter cable, right?

Comment: @FreeMan well, it's complicated. There's a lot of terms like quick/rapid/turbo that all mean slightly different things. It could be opting-in to 12v instead of 5v, or it might just tell the 5v charger not to limit output to 1A. Those modes don't guarantee a certain performance, only that a threshold condition was met, which could just be smarts on the phone/charger shaking hands, regardless of the connection quality. A good charger and a good phone will report "~rapid" even with a crappy (yet otherwise compliant) cable. There's good aftermarket brands like anker, but OEMs are generally fastest

Comment: Would like to add a double socket for her to plug chargers into, but easiest option is to come off this socket rather than lift carpetnand floor boards to get to the ring main. But wanted to make sure it was safe and legal to use this socket

Answer (score 1):

You probably can provided the circuit is RCD protected.
**All** *new* sockets **must** be RCD protected.

And the boiler must be plugged into an *unswitched* socket outlet. This is so the only way of isolating the boiler is withdrawing the plug, which guarantees isolation of live and neutral. Some switched sockets only switch the live.